# Upload files to WordPress site from iOS app

Tags: ios, wordpress, file-upload

So I want my iOS app to upload files created by mobile users to my WordPress site.

- Users will locally create JSON files.
- The files will be uploaded using the WordPress REST API as [Media](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/) files. I have enabled uploading non-image media files for that.
- I want the app to upload these files to the site with a single "uploader" site account. The credentials will have to be securely stored in the app at build time.

**Questions:**

- Is it a good scheme to upload user files to my site?
- What credentials would I need to embed in the app upload files?
- Do I need a WP plugin to make it work?
- What is a good way to secure/obscure those credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I needed to set `define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true);` on `wp-config.php` to allow uploading JSON files to media.

I also created an "Editor" account that would be allowed to upload and delete media.

Then I played with the WP REST API, which is messy and badly documented. I was able to authenticate using basic Authorization in the header.

I was able to upload JSON files but I couldn't update/overwrite them later without deleting them first.

So after lots of small annoyances I decided to use Amazon S3 for this. I setup uploading in half an hour. I was stretching WP too much for this task.